# Minimization of amount in the change coins problem using the dynamic programing approach

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

I'm learning the dynamic programming approach to solve the coins change problem, I don't understand the substitution part

Given: `amount=9, coins = [6,5,1]`,

the instructor simplified it with this function:

`minCoins = min {(9-6)+1 , (9-5)+1, (9-1) +1} = min{4, 5, 9} = 4`

I don't understand the logic of this `min` method: why we say that to change amount of 9 coins, we can simply, take the minimum of: 9  - {all coins} +1 ?

here's a Gif that visualizes the instructor's approach: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx2cG.gif

(*taken from the [Algorithmic Toolbox course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithmic-toolbox)/ instructor: Prof. Pavel A. Pevzner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is wrong (I would like to see where exactly this formula appears in the course, it is not in the gif you linked).

The correct formula is the following:
Let $n$ be your amount. Let minCoins be an array of $n+1$ elements indexed from $0$ to $n$, where minCoins$[i]$ is the minimum amount of coins needed to give change for the amount $i$. Let $c_1, \dots, c_k$ be the denominations of coins you have available.

Then minCoins$[0]=0$ and, for $i>0$:
$
\text{minCoins}[i] = \min_{\substack{j=1,\dots,k\\c_j \le i}} \{1 + \text{minCoins}[i-c_j] \}.
$

In your specific example:

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{minCoins}[9] &= \min \{\text{minCoins}[9-6]+1 , \text{minCoins}[9-5]+1, \text{minCoins}[9-1] +1\} \\
&= \min \{\text{minCoins}[3]+1 , \text{minCoins}[4]+1, \text{minCoins}[8] +1\} \\
&= \min\{ 3+1, 4+1, 3+1\} \\
&=  \min\{ 4, 5, 4\} = 4.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Another shoot from the lecture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWqBo.png

Comment: This confirms what I have written. The minimum is not among $(9-6)+1$, $(9-5)+1$, and $(9-1) +1$ but rather among minCoins[9−6]+1, minCoins[9−5]+1, and minCoins[9−1]+1.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but unfortunately, it's still the same vagueness. 
is this formula is for memorization only? can one understand its proof, so if I had a similar problem I can use or develop another formula based on it. I think this is more important than knowing the formula itself.

Comment: No, the formula works perfectly fine for a "bottom-up" dynamic programming. Start from minCoins[0], whose values is known, and then compute minCoins$[i]$ for $i=1, \dots,n$ in increasing order of $i$ by applying the recursive definition I gave in my answer. Notice that it only depends on values of minCoins$[x]$ for $x<i$, which are all already known at this point.

Comment: The intuition behind the recursive formula is the following: Imagine you are giving change for a (non-zero) amount $i$ by handing out coins. You'll need a coin of *some* of the available denominations $c_j$ (for simplicity think that is the last coin you are handing out, even though it doesn't really matter). Since you are using $c_j$, the optimal solution will be exactly the minimum amount of coins needed to give change for the remaining amount $i-c_j$, plus 1 (to account for the coin $c_j$ itself). Of course you don't know *which* coin $c_j$ you should use.

Comment: This is where the minimum in the recursive formula comes in. You can essentially "guess" the right coin $c_j$ by trying them all and selecting the one that results in the best solution. Since you are guaranteed to examine the "right" coin, you know that the minimum will be taken among a set of values that include the optimal solution (and the other values cannot be smaller than the optimal solution). This shows that you are computing exactly the minimum amount of coins needed to give change for amount $i$ (provided that you have already computed the optimal solution for all amounts $\le i$).